# Spaces, line breaks, tabs ; are they affect server performance?

Tags: php

Spaces, line breaks, tabs ; are they affect server performance ?

I'm  in the road of learning PHP and before I go further with my current coding style, i want to make sure :
  Are line breaks and spaces affect the performance of the server ? Usually, I always add them for readibility. for example in the following code :

```
import('something') ;
$var = 'A' ;
$varb = 'B' ;
switch($var) {
  case 'A' :
    doSomething() ;
    doAnotherThing() ;
    break ;
}
if ($var == $varb) { header('Location: somewhere.php') ; }
```

Summary,

1. I add space before a semicolon
2. I add space after and before variable value assignment and comparison
3. I add space between ) and {
4. Usually I add a line break after { if the code following it consist of multiple statements.
5. Inside the curly bracket, I always start with a space before the first statement and ended it with another space after the last statement's semicolon
6. I always give a 2-space-width tab for every child elements
7. I always add a space after 'Location:' inside header function.
8. I always add space before semicolon for each case condition

This style is cool for me, I like it, its tidy and it makes me easier to debug, what i wonder is, will this kind of coding style hurt/burden the system ? Will it makes server slower by re-formatting my codes ? So far i got no formatting error.

Thank you for your kind answers

Answer (score 4):

**No. The extra formatting will not affect performance at all*.**

Choose the coding style you like -- that is also acceptable for the team/project/existing code -- and, most importantly, *be consistent*. (Using an editor with customizable syntax formatting is helpful.)

Happy coding.

---

*While it could be argued that an *insignificant* increase IO may occur and an *insignificant* greater amount of symbols must be read by the [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), the final result is: there will be **no performance decrease.**

Comment: thank you for the answer, one of the reason I like PHP, coding style is not server-dependent; unlike some other language which can result in fatal compile error when you forgot a space, or indent.

Comment: these excuses are useless. one who understand the matter, don't need them. But usual PHP coder with his superstitions would spot your [practical] and nothing else.

Comment: @AzDesign It depends on language -- I believe that *good code formatting* is a requirement to write "good code" in language, and this is a *learned habit*. Even ugly code will compile/run :) Python and Haskell depend on (indent) white-space. Java, SmallTalk, JavaScript, C#, D, SQL, Scala, Perl, Ruby, C/C++, Eiffel, PHP (just to name a few) only require white-space to separate tokens, with a few little caveats. Some of the languages mentioned have official "style guides" (e.g. Python and Java) and others have "[industry] recommendations".

Comment: Actually, i think disk IO will only increase if (and only if) the file is at the limit of the file block. Files are stored on the harddisk in blocks, so even if you read 1 byte, or 10 bytes, the system reads it as 1 block. Unless the file happens to be just below the size of 1 block, and you add spaces until it is bigger than that block, causing it to need 2 block read instead of 1 block read to load file. But all in all, hard disk are getting faster now a days, so does it make a difference?

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife You are correct. The increase is *insignificant* and is "amortized away". I don't know why I had "substantially" in there, which makes it sound relevant ;-) The issue is further complicated due to read-ahead and buffering. I was just feeling ... pedantic. More CPU cycles, *as irrelevant as they may be*, are (potentially) used.

Comment: But cpu and hard disk are getting faster and better. So this small increase in cpu or io load is moot in 1 months time anyway. I prefer to have codes that is easy to develop and maintain, over codes that is hard to maintain but runs just 1 millisec faster :).

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife !!!! I did not mean for this to say this will lead to any performance decrease. I really didn't know people would jump on that so. !!!!

Comment: @pst Just choose a formating style that you like and stick to it. It makes it easier for you to code in future. I usually configures my IDE to auto format for me, so that when I am reading other people's codes, i just let the IDE format it to the style I like.

Comment: if performance is so important you maybe want to use a different language

Answer (score 2):

No and yes (but mostly insignificant).  Slightly different way thinking about the issue from @pst's answer (not even thinking about disk io) but same end result.

Simplified php behind the scenes - PHP is compiled to bytecodes on runtime.  During compile, all spaces and comments are filtered down/out among many other actions.

Filtering out more whitespace from less is mostly insignificant compared with all the other actions.

The compiled bytecodes are what actually gets run.

But let's say you are running a major website, have 1000s of web servers and each php file is getting called millions of times a day.  All those previously insignificant bits of time add up.  But so does all the other stuff that the compiler is doing.  At the point that this all becomes an issue for you, it's time to start looking into PHP caching/accelerators. (Or more likely long before this.)

Basically, those cachers/accelerators cache the compiled bytecodes the first time they are produced after the files are modified.  Subsequent calls to the same file skip the compiling phase and go right to the cached compiled bytecodes.  At that stage all the whitespace no longer exists.  So, it becomes a moot point because they only ever compile once.